# Use ActiveSupport 2.3.5 in a Rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, activesupport

Is it possible to use ActiveSupport 2.3.5 within a Rails 3 application?

I have my Rails 3 application setup and working, however, a gem I would like to use to work with an API only supports ActiveSupport 2.3.5. Is there a way of running the two in parallel?

For further information - the application can be seen here:

https://github.com/dannymcc/Beanstalk-Deployment

and the gem can be seen here:

https://github.com/iSabanin/beanstalkapp

If not, is the only alternative to downgrade to Rails 2.3?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try forking the repo and change:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<activeresource>, ["= 2.3.5"])
```

in `beanstalkapp.gemspec` to

```
s.add_runtime_dependency(%q<activeresource>, ["= 3.0.4"])
```

After that you can use it in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'beanstalkapp', :git => 'https://github.com/dannymcc/beanstalkapp.git'
```

Comment: Is there a way of then installing the gem from my fork instead of the authors?

Comment: For some reason that errors.

MacBook:beanstalkdeployments danny$ bundle install
Fetching https://github.com/dannymcc/beanstalkapp
error: The requested URL returned error: 500 while accessing https://github.com/dannymcc/beanstalkapp/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "https://github.com/dannymcc/beanstalkapp" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/beanstalkapp-51b398041f9fd5bbc2d49d0b1aef40611947a2f6" --bare --no-hardlinks`. Cannot complete bundling.